Python, Selenium AWS Lambda function
Does anybody know how to run a Python function with Selenium which gets data from a webpage like the AWS Lambda function? When I run my Lambda function it hits the time limit (although I set the time limit to 1 min). I've tried running it on an AWS EC2 instance but, now, it throws this error:
this version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 123.0.6312.105

I tried to find Chrome browser version 114, but unsuccessfully. When run my function into the Docker container it returns code 127 and I found information that this is a Chromedriver issue
I don't think that the reason in my code, but just in case I add it here:
import csv
import json
import time
import boto3
import decimal
import datetime
# To detect the latest version of the Chromedriver binary installed on the system
# import chromedriver_binary

from io import StringIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Own except class to handle errors
class Error(Exception):
    pass

# Define the function which returns third Friday of the specific month
def third_Friday(month: int, year: int) -> str:
    weekday_1 = datetime.date(year, month, 1).weekday()
    day_diff = 4 - weekday_1\
    if weekday_1 <= 4 else 11 - weekday_1
    return datetime.date(year, month, 15 + day_diff).isoformat()

# Wrap all logic into a function
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Define aws s3 bucket client
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
                             aws_access_key_id='MY_KEY',
                             aws_secret_access_key='MY_SECRET')

    # Define todays' date
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    # Define file name
    fname = third_Friday(today.month, today.year).replace('-', '')
    
    # Get data from bucket
    bucket = s3_client\
        .get_object(Bucket='BUCKET_ID',
                    Key='BUCKET_KEY' + fname + '.csv')
    
    raw = str(bucket['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')).strip('\'').split('\n')
    header = raw[0].split(',')
    df = []
    for row in raw[1:]:
        slpited = row.split(',')
        if len(slpited) == len(header):
            df.append(slpited)
    # Config webdriver
    try:
        opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--headless")
        opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        opts.add_argument("--single-process")
        opts.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        # Run driver
        driver = Chrome(options=opts)
        # Get page content
        driver.get("SOME_URL")
        time.sleep(10)
        tables = driver\
            .find_elements(By.XPATH, 
                        value="//table[@class='Box-cui__sc-6h7t1h-0 TableComponents__StyledTable-cui__sc-19kjwg0-3 dISGpF']")
        for value in tables[0].text.split('\n'):
            if 'Russell 1000 Index (RIR)' in value:
                index_value = decimal.Decimal(value.split(' ')[-1])

        df.append([fname, 'RIR', 'RIR', index_value])
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        df.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        csv_writter = csv.writer(csv_buffer)
        csv_writter.writerow([col.strip() for col in header])
        for row in df:
            csv_writter.writerow([str(el).strip() for el in row])
        # Write back content to remote storage
        s3_resource.Object('BUCKET_ID',
                        'BUCKET_KEY' + fname + '.csv').put(
                            Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
        
        # Close driver
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
    except Error as err:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": repr(err)
        }
    
    # Return statements for lambda Function
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps("OK")
    }

In advance thank you for any help
Tried to run my function by loading it manually with a zip archive with the browser and the Chromedriver as well. Tried running it in a Docker container, tried running it in an EC2 instance tried deploying it with Sam CLI

Isn't the error self explanatory? Download the corresponding version to the chrome you have installed here

@0x00 It didn't help. I installed Chrome version 114, ran the code and it threw code 127. Probably it is related to libatk-1.0.so.0 library.
But Thank you very much!!! At least I managed to install Chrome v114, I couldn't find a link to do so, but after you give me a link I've done this. Thanks a lot, I'm continuing to investigate the issue.
Thanks!!!
